# Does IPFS works over etherium?

Tags: solidity, ipfs

Does IPFS has etherium smart conttacts? Is it a whole other Blockchain?

Answer (score 1):

IPFS isn't a blockchain, is a distributed file system that use a [Distributed hash table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_hash_table)

Comment: Despite what the name says not even a file system, but Internet cache. IPFS does not store files, it only holds them temporarily.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are talking about something that is built 'on-top' of IPFS, or an abstraction. You may be thinking of or heard of, Filecoin. Which is a layer on top of IPFS, incentivizing it.

Currently it is common to 'access' stored data on IPFS from a blockchain like Ethereum.